# Unity is Single Thread by how do WWW with coroutine work Async

Tags: unity, c#

When I used **HttpWebRequest** and **HttpWebResponse** classes for an API calling my game suddenly halt for some seconds but as i used same API calling through **WWW** with coroutine, it didn't halt.

I heard that unity is single thread but why my game not halt as i used WWW with coroutine? and is i am getting right that  HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse are not better than WWW?

Comment: Any code you write in Start, Update, or a Coroutine (among others) is run on a single thread, but that doesn't stop you or the engine from using additional threads for other work. Things like LoadLevelAsync can perform their work on another thread while the main game loop keeps ticking and rendering frames.

Comment: WWW is a customyieldinstruction and so can be used with/as a coroutine.

Answer (score -1):

A `coroutine` runs on the main thread but when ever you use a `yield return`, it tells the program to stop operating this function, save the state of the function and continue executing the rest of the frame.
You can determine when the function would allow the rest to execute by returning different values by `yield return`.
for example when you say `yield return null;` the method will resume functioning as soon as the updates have completed their work.
but if you use `yield return new waitForEndOfFrame();`, the function will resume as soon as all the work in the frame is done and the screen is ready to be updated.
usually when using a `WWW`, you would check for the `isDone` property and keep checking and coming back to the function until `isDone` returns true.

```
WWW www = new WWW(URL);
yield return www;
while (!www.isDone)
{
    yield return www.progress;
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
{
    Debug.Log(www.error);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.text))
{
    Debug.Log(www.text);
}
```

Comment: The `while (!www.isDone)` block here looks odd. Coming right after a `yield return www`, this line won't execute until the WWW request is completed anyway, so the `while` just gets skipped. Yielding progress also looks strange, since progress is a float and not a YieldInstruction. Did you mean to loop each frame, reporting progress until the WWW request is complete?

Comment: the while executes fine and yield return www.progress is like yield return 0 and these lines execute one after another. maybe with the yield return www I wouldn't need the while but just for being safe it's better to be there. I copied it from my working game so it runs fine. and I just wanted to show how the coroutine returns to continue execution. feel free to edit @DMGregory